# Python Playwright Evaluate JS on hidden input

Tags: javascript, playwright-python

I'm trying to execute a javascript it works in console of the browser but playwright can not execute it.

Item is located inside a frame and is hidden.

```
    page.evaluate("""(answer)=>{
        document.getElementById('tc-answer').value = answer;
    }
    """, answer)
```

I may be doing something dumb here but i can not figure out what is wrong :( The error is below

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:178:30), <anonymous>:2:67)
    at UtilityScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:185:19)
    at UtilityScript.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)
```

Comment: if that's inside an `iframe`, `document.getElementById('tc-answer')` will always return null. You need to get the frame first and query on its document. `frame = page.frames()[0] frame.evaluate(...`

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov tried your method but get the error.

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Also, tried this with no luck.

page.frames('/html/body/div[4]/iframe').evaluate("""(answer)=>{
                document.getElementById('...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this method...

```
iframe1 = page.query_selector('xpath=/html/body/div[4]/iframe').content_frame()
iframe1.evaluate("...
```